# What is the use case for overriding default login-processing-url in spring security

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

Here is a sample config for spring security form login

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="false">
      <form-login login-processing-url="/static/j_spring_security_check"
                  login-page="/login"
                  authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t"/>
  </http>
```

Now if I dont specify any explicit  login-processing-url spring assumes it as only "/j_spring_security_check". I could not find  any type of functional difference between default and the overridden one and found spring handles the change seamlessly. I tried to do google to understand when should we override it. None of the answer satisfied me.

So when and why should we override the default login-processing-url? And most importantly is there any usecase when we "must" override the default?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to hide the fact that you are using Spring Security, you should override the `login-processing-url` to something like "forms/login", as well as the username and password form parameters. This help hide the framework that you are using to secure your site.

The `<form-login>` tag is a short hand for configuring the [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html). This filter will only be invoked by the URL specified in `login-processing-url` and will use the value set for `username-parameter` and `password-parameter` as the username and password from the request.

Comment: Thats what I found after searching. But I was not too sure if that is the only use case. Do you have any idea how Spring handles the overriding?

Comment: I've updated the answer with additional details. It's all just a java filter in the end, and `form-login` configures the bean properties.

Comment: Thanks Jay for the details. I am confused because I am not able to understand what hiding will be achieved by simply "/j_spring_security_check" to "/static/j_spring_security_check"? In "Spring In Action" I see this as an example and am not able to understand whats the point if its simply for the hiding

Comment: I haven't read through that book yet, but I do have a copy. Looking at the section for Logging Out, they also change the logout URL and state: "But so that [the logout URL] doesn't collide with how we've set up DispatcherServlet, we need to override the filter's URL much as we did for the login form." So my guess is that they only changed it so it doesn't collide with their MVC configuration.

Comment: Excellent ..thanks Jay. I myself did some bit of research and found out indeed information hiding is the only usecase.

Comment: The username and password parameters are just themselves, see source code from UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter  `public static final String SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_USERNAME_KEY = "username";
 public static final String SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_PASSWORD_KEY = "password";`